# Missing Spanish wordnet from NLTK

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, wordnet

I am trying to use the Spanish Wordnet from the Open Multilingual Wordnet in NLTK 3.0, but it seems that it was not downloaded with the 'omw' package. For example, with a code like the following:

```
from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn

print [el.lemma_names('spa') for el in wn.synsets('bank')]
```

I get the following error message:

```
IOError: No such file or directory: u'***/nltk_data/corpora/omw/spa/wn-data-spa.tab'
```

According to the [documentation](http://www.nltk.org/howto/wordnet.html), Spanish should be included, in the 'omw' package, but it was not downloaded with it. Do you know why this could happen?

Comment: What does `wn.langs()` give you? Also, which version of NLTK and Python?

Comment: BTW, useful link if having trouble installing NLTK on Ubuntu: http://askubuntu.com/a/527408/93794

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here's the full error traceback if a language is missing from the Open Multilingual WordNet in your `nltk_data` directory:

```
>>> from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn
>>> wn.synsets('bank')[0].lemma_names('spa')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk/corpus/reader/wordnet.py", line 418, in lemma_names
    self._wordnet_corpus_reader._load_lang_data(lang)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk/corpus/reader/wordnet.py", line 1070, in _load_lang_data
    f = self._omw_reader.open('{0:}/wn-data-{0:}.tab'.format(lang))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk/corpus/reader/api.py", line 198, in open
    stream = self._root.join(file).open(encoding)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk/data.py", line 309, in join
    return FileSystemPathPointer(_path)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk/compat.py", line 380, in _decorator
    return init_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk/data.py", line 287, in __init__
    raise IOError('No such file or directory: %r' % _path)
IOError: No such file or directory: u'/home/alvas/nltk_data/corpora/omw/spa/wn-data-spa.tab'
```

So the first thing is to check whether it's installed automatically:

```
>>> import nltk
>>> nltk.download('omw')
[nltk_data] Downloading package omw to /home/alvas/nltk_data...
[nltk_data]   Package omw is already up-to-date!
Tru
```

Then you should go and check the nltk_data and find that 'spa' folder is missing:

```
alvas@ubi:~/nltk_data/corpora/omw$ ls
als  arb  cmn  dan  eng  fas  fin  fra  fre  heb  ita  jpn  mcr  msa  nor  pol  por  README  tha
```

So here's the short term solution:

```
$ wget http://compling.hss.ntu.edu.sg/omw/wns/spa.zip
$ mkdir ~/nltk_data/corpora/omw/spa
$ unzip -p spa.zip mcr/wn-data-spa.tab > ~/nltk_data/corpora/omw/spa/wn-data-spa.tab
```

Alternatively, you can simply copy the file from `nltk_data/corpora/omw/mcr/wn-data-spa.tab`.

[out]:

```
>>> from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn
>>> wn.synsets('bank')[0].lemma_names('spa')
[u'margen', u'orilla', u'vera']
```

Now the `lemma_names()` should work for Spanish, if you're looking for other languages from the Open Multilingusl Wordnet, you can browse here (http://compling.hss.ntu.edu.sg/omw/) and then download and put in the respective nltk_data directory.

The long term solution would be to ask the devs from NLTK and OMW project to update their datasets for their NLTK API.

Answer (score 5):

We (OMW) have prepared a fix and will push it out soon.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow Francis! My chance to give best answers on wordnet questions is now gone ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this project: https://github.com/lingeringsocket/wn-mcr-transform

And then use nltk corpus normally like in English but using Spanish.

Basically will replace all knowledge in nltk corpus from English to Spanish using MCR 3.0 corpus.

Works for:

- Catalan - cat
- English - eng
- Euskara - eus
- Galician - glg
- Portuguese - por
- Spanish - spa